# Symfony2 : Resizing uploaded images

Tags: file-upload, symfony, image-resizing

Is there any way to resize pictures while uploading them in Symfony2 ?

The [ImagineAvalancheBundle](http://knpbundles.com/moreweb/ImagineBundle) only allows to resize images to thumbnails when retrieving them, which is not really performant to me.

Besides, the UploadedFile object retreived when posting data doesn't seems to have resizing methods...

Any Idea ?

Comment: The imagine bundle caches the resampled images, so performance is not really an issue, unless you have a very low cache-hit rate (in most cases, with user-specific uploads)

Comment: I have the same problem, and I can't use the local cache. I'm offloading the resized images to a CDN.

Comment: I just posted [a solution for creating thumbnails using LiipImagineBundle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15047281/use-liipimaginebundle-to-resize-image-after-upload/15669193#15669193), something similar may work with ImagineAvalancheBundle as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem you are asking for.

The main issue is that the bundle resizes and/or crops the images directly.
So that can take a lot of time with big images and if many images are expected per page.

So I've fix this issue by calling directly after *imageupload* the `resize()` function to the image.
Hence, I save (copy) the resized image to the filesystem at the server. Obviously I store the path of the image into the database to can load it directly if needed.

I tried the included *memcache* of the *imageresize* bundle but in my case it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem for a project that i'm actually developing. I searched a lot on the net and found nothing realy performant and also easy to use for non-tech people.

I created a bundle to be able to upload with [jquery file upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) and crop with [jcrop](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html) with some other functions.

[ComurImageBundle](https://github.com/comur/ComurImageBundle)

Answer (score 0):

What is exactly your goal ? Resize and crop ? Other ?

I don't understand why you say that the bundle resize to thumbnail only as you can define precisely your resize preset through config :

```
  # app/config/config.yml

    avalanche_imagine:
        filters:
            my_thumb:
                type:    thumbnail
                options: { size: [120, 90], mode: outbound }
```

Comment: read properly, he didnt say that "bundle resize to thumbnail only", he said that "only allows to resize images ... when retrieving them", ignore the dotted part