# Dynamic filter with liipImagineBundle

Tags: image, symfony, symfony-2.1, liipimaginebundle

I'm using liipImagineBundle and am trying to apply a filter directly into a controller.

In the doc I found two sections in which explains how to use liipImagineBundle from the controller. This one https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle#using-the-controller-as-a-service

```
public function indexAction()
{
    // RedirectResponse object
    $imagemanagerResponse = $this->container
        ->get('liip_imagine.controller')
            ->filterAction(
                $this->getRequest(),
                'uploads/foo.jpg',      // original image you want to apply a filter to
                'my_thumb'              // filter defined in config.yml
    );

    // string to put directly in the "src" of the tag <img>
    $srcPath = $imagemanagerResponse->headers->get('location');

    // ..
}
```

And https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/filters.md#dynamic-filters

```
public function filterAction(Request $request, $path, $filter)
{
$targetPath = $this->cacheManager->resolve($request, $path, $filter);
if ($targetPath instanceof Response) {
    return $targetPath;
}

$image = $this->dataManager->find($filter, $path);

$filterConfig = $this->filterManager->getFilterConfiguration();
$config = $filterConfig->get($filter);
$config['filters']['thumbnail']['size'] = array(300, 100);
$filterConfig->set($filter, $config);

$response = $this->filterManager->get($request, $filter, $image, $path);

if ($targetPath) {
    $response = $this->cacheManager->store($response, $targetPath, $filter);
}

return $response;
}
```

I tested as indicated in "Using the controller as a service" and it works, the problem I have is that I don't know how to access the filter settings to modify it.

```
liip_imagine:
driver:               gd
web_root:             %kernel.root_dir%/../web
data_root:            %kernel.root_dir%/../web
cache_mkdir_mode:     0777
cache_prefix:         /media/cache
cache:                web_path
cache_clearer:        true
data_loader:          filesystem
controller_action:    liip_imagine.controller:filterAction
formats:              []
filter_sets:
    my_thumb:
        filters:
            crop: { start: [0, 0], size: [200, 150] }
    my_paste:
        quality: 90
        filters:
            paste: { start: [30, 60], image: ../web/uploads/images/firma.jpg }
```

The second, really, I don't understand when he says "With a custom data loader...".

In the example he is only modifying the method filteraction() from the ImagineController class (Liip\ImagineBundle\Controller). I wonder how I can modify that method dynamically? For example from my controller indexAction().

Also i have read this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166719/loading-your-custom-filters-with-liipimaginebundle where @NSCoder says that "You can use the built in filter and modify their configuration." but i don't understand it.

I've been looking for several days but I haven't found an example from which to start.

Answer (score 6):

Looking for some more I found another LiipImagineBundle topic ([Use LiipImagineBundle to Resize Image after Upload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15047281/use-liipimaginebundle-to-resize-image-after-upload)) that has helped me to do what I wanted..

here I leave the code I use to dynamically apply a filter

```
public function indexAction()
{

    $container = $this->container;

    # The controller service
    $imagemanagerResponse = $container->get('liip_imagine.controller');

    # The filter configuration service
    $filterConfiguration = $container->get('liip_imagine.filter.configuration');

    # Get the filter settings
    $configuracion = $filterConfiguration->get('my_thumb');

    # Update filter settings
    $configuracion['filters']['crop']['size'] = array(50, 150);
    $configuracion['filters']['crop']['start'] = array(10, 10);
    $filterConfiguration->set('my_thumb', $configuracion);

    # Apply the filter
    $imagemanagerResponse->filterAction($this->getRequest(),'uploads/images/logo.jpg','my_thumb');

    # Move the img from temp
    $fileTemporal = new File('media/cache/my_thumb/uploads/images/logo.jpg');

    $fileTemporal->move('uploads/images/', 'mini-logo.jpg');

    ####################################

}
```