# how to resize the original image after upload with LiipImagineBundle on symfony3?

Tags: image, symfony, upload, resize, liipimaginebundle

I saw this link and it's close that i want.
[Use LiipImagineBundle to Resize Image after Upload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15047281/use-liipimaginebundle-to-resize-image-after-upload?rq=1)

I use symfony 3 with the bundle LiipImagineBundle.
I just want to resize the ORIGINAL image in the class controller just after uploaded it.
I don't want to create a thumbnail on the cache folder.

Let's see the sample below:
If a user upload a file 1800*1200 i want to resize it to 800*600 on the file system and I don't want to keep the file 1800*1200.

Is it possible with LiipImagineBundle ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this by implementing a special filter (crop) just like this

```
# LiipImagineBundle
liip_imagine:
    resolvers:
        default:
            web_path:
                web_root: ~
                cache_prefix: media/cache
    filter_sets:
        image_xlarge:
            filters:
                crop: { size: [800, 600], mode: outbound }
```

referrer http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/LiipImagineBundle/filters/sizing.html#cropping-images

Comment: hi Yamen thank you for your response, but I want to resize it from the controller. after upload file

Comment: Noboby has an idea ?

Comment: acutally this will create a new image with the new size so what you can do is to create the new image and delete the old one