# Can I resize an image on upload in symfony 5?

Tags: file-upload, image-resizing, symfony5

I am trying to figure out how to resize an image on upload with symfony 5. Actually my fileupload is working perfectly, but it would be such a relief not to resize all my pics before I have to upload them.

Is there a way I can do this?

Here is my upload code:

```php
if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){ 
    $imageFile = $form->get('file')->getData(); 
    if($imageFile) { 
        #CAN'T RESIZE HERE BEFORE UPLOAD ??? 
        $imageFileName = $fileUploader->upload($imageFile); 
        $image->setFilename($imageFileName); 
    }

    #.....persist - flush etc.
}
```

Comment: If it's *just before* upload symfony is irrelevant here, it'll be happening in the browser so this is a javascript question. Try [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=image%20resize) instead.

Comment: [Yes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15047281/use-liipimaginebundle-to-resize-image-after-upload).

Answer (score 1):

First this is my controller with a method to upload an image from a form:

```php
       /**
     * @Route("/admin/image/new", name="admin_image_new")
     */
    public function newImage(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $manager, FileUploader $fileUploader, ImageResizeService $imageResize)
    {

        $image = new Image();
        $form = $this->createForm(ImageType::class, $image);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        
        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){

            $imageFile = $form->get('file')->getData();
           
            if($imageFile) {
                
                $imageFileName = $fileUploader->upload($imageFile);
                $image->setFilename($imageFileName);
               
            }
            
            $manager->persist($image);
            $manager->flush();
            
            $this->addFlash('success', 'Image added successfully !');

            $imageName = $image->getFilename();

            $fullSizeImgWebPath = $fileUploader->getTargetDirectory().'/'.$imageName;

           [$width,$height] = getimagesize($fullSizeImgWebPath);
            
            
            
            if($width > $height){
                $width = 1500;
                $height =  1000;
               // $imageResize->writeThumbnail($fullSizeImgWebPath, 1500, 1000);
            } else if($width == $height){
                $width = 300;
                $height =  300;
                //$imageResize->writeThumbnail($fullSizeImgWebPath, 300, 300);
            } else {  
                $width = 1500;
                $height =  2254;
                //$imageResize->writeThumbnail($fullSizeImgWebPath,1000,1600);
            }

            $imageResize->writeThumbnail($fullSizeImgWebPath, $width, $height);
            return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_image');
           
        }

        
        return $this->render('admin/image/new_image.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'AdminImageController',
            'form'=> $form->createView()
        ]);
    }
```

I created a service to resize the uploaded image:

```php
class ImageResizeService {

        /**
     * Write a thumbnail image using Imagine
     * 
     * @param string $thumbAbsPath full absolute path to attachment directory e.g. /var/www/project1/images/thumbs/
     */
    public function writeThumbnail($thumbAbsPath, $width, $height) {
        $imagine = new Imagine;
        $image   = $imagine->open($thumbAbsPath);
        $size    = new Box($width, $height);

        $image->thumbnail($size,ImageInterface::THUMBNAIL_OUTBOUND)
            ->save($thumbAbsPath);                                         
    }
}
```